# How to call another action from actions in Vuex/Vues?

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to update a list of *sites* after deleting one of them by calling the `getSites()` method like below

### Code

```
import http from 'services/http.service';
import logging from 'services/logging.service';

const sites = http('sites', localStorage);

export default {
    getSites({dispatch}) {
        console.log('getSites')
        sites.all().then((response) => {
            dispatch('setSites', response.data.results);
        });
    },
    deleteSite({dispatch}, site) {
        return sites.delete(site).then(() => {
            this.getSites()  // <-------- doesn't works
        });
    },
};
```

I get the following error

> deletion failed ReferenceError: getSites is not defined

#### Question

How should I call fetch my new list of items? Or Should I do it inside my component `then()`?

Comment: little late but wouldn't it work to do `dispatch('getSites')` instead of `this.getSites()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remove the call from the *actions.js* and did it from inside my component method:

```
import actions from 'vuex/actions';

export default{
    // …
    methods: {
        // …
        delete_site(site){
            return this.deleteSite(site).then(response => {
                this.getSites();  // <----------- call from here
            });
        },
    vuex: {
        actions: {
            getSites: actions.getSites,
            deleteSite: actions.deleteSite,
        }
    }
}
```